# I have issue when I insert new contact

Tags: android

```
 String DisplayName = "XYZ";
 String MobileNumber = "123456";
 String HomeNumber = "1111";
 String WorkNumber = "2222";
 String emailID = "email@nomail.com";
 String company = "bad";
 String jobTitle = "abcd";


                    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                            .build());

                    //------------------------------------------------------ Names
                    if(DisplayName != null)
                    {
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, DisplayName).build());
                    }                       
                    //------------------------------------------------------ Mobile Number
                    if(MobileNumber != null)
                    {
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, MobileNumber)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                                .build());
                    }

                    //------------------------------------------------------ Home Numbers
                    if(HomeNumber != null)
                    {
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, HomeNumber)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                                .build());
                    }

                    //------------------------------------------------------ Work Numbers
                    if(WorkNumber != null)
                    {
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, WorkNumber)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, 
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK)
                                .build());
                    }

                    //------------------------------------------------------ Email
                    if(emailID != null)
                    {
                         ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, emailID)
                                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)
                                    .build());
                    }

                    //------------------------------------------------------ Organization
                    if(!company.equals("") && !jobTitle.equals(""))
                    {
                        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY, company)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE, jobTitle)
                                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TYPE_WORK)
                                .build());
                    }

                    // Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact                  
                    try 
                    {
                        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {               
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

My code is as above, but when it call `applyBatch`() function it gives error as
 `"The method applyBatch(String, ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>) is undefined for the type ContentResolver"` 
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

That function is only available since API level 5 (which is Android 2.0). Either use a newer phone, or create an emulator for a newer api level.
If you must use below api level 5 then working with contacts is a bit harder.